# Return all the second highest valued rows SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table called `bookings`, containing 3 columns: `hotelid`, `timestampOfBooking`and `numberOfGuests`.

How do I return all the dates on which the **second** highest beds were booked (the amount of beds booked is the same as the number of guests).

In other words, I'm looking for the dates on which the **second** maximum number of `numberOfGuests`occur. This means that in the event of a tie (where there is more than 1 date on which the described condition applies), it should return all those dates. In the event that all the dates have exactly the same `numberOfGuests` the query should return nothing.

If possible, I would only like to have one column in the query result that contains those specific dates.

Example:

```
hotelid      timestampOfBooking      numberOfGuests 
  11             22/11/2021                 2
  34             23/11/2021                 2
  30             23/11/2021                 5
  19             24/11/2021                 7
  8              25/11/2021                 12
  34             25/11/2021                 5
```

In this case two dates should be in the result: 23/11/2021 and 24/11/2021 as they both had 7 `numberOfGuests`. The max `numberOfGuests` here is 17 (occurs on 25/11/2021) and 7 is the **second** highest, explaining why 23/11/2021 `(2 + 5)` and 24/11/2021 `(7)` are returned. The final result should look like this:

```
dates
23/11/2021
24/11/2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` with `SUM(numberOfGuests)` IN `DESC`:

```
SELECT timestampOfBooking, total_beds FROM
(
   select timestampOfBooking, 
          sum(numberOfGuests) as total_beds,
          dense_rank() over (order by sum(numberOfGuests) DESC) as rnk
   from bookings
   group by timestampOfBooking
) as sq
where rnk = 2
```

**Method 2:**

Using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT timestampOfBooking, 
       SUM(numberOfGuests) AS total_beds
FROM bookings
GROUP BY timestampOfBooking
HAVING sum(numberOfGuests)=
   (
    SELECT distinct SUM(numberOfGuests) AS total_beds
    FROM bookings
    GROUP BY timestampOfBooking
    ORDER BY total_beds DESC
    OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1
   );
```

Both the methods will give you same output.

Working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4b19862f1e3f01b11cfab834e9c3a19b)

Comment: Would u know of any way to do it witouth DENSE_RANK()?

Comment: Do you want it without `DENSE_RANK()` or without `WINDOW FUNCTIONS` itself

Comment: By preference without window functions

Comment: Updated the answer without window functions (using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`)